# Dates in JSON format

Tags: json, pandas, date, dataframe

I would like to write a (pandas) DataFrame to a json file. But one of my columns is a date and when I read from the json file the date format is Miliseconds(?)

```
    from pandas import DataFrame, read_json
    from datetime import date

    A = {'a': [date(2019,1,1),date(2019,1,2),date(2019,1,2)], 'b': [4,5,6]}
    df = DataFrame(A)
    print(df)

    filename = r'C:\temp\Export_DataFrame.json'
    #to json file
    Export = df.to_json(filename)

    #import from json
    df2 = read_json(filename)
    print(df2)
```

gives me the following result:

```
                a  b
    0  2019-01-01  4
    1  2019-01-02  5
    2  2019-01-02  6

                   a  b
    0  1546300800000  4
    1  1546387200000  5
    2  1546387200000  6
```

When reading the json file how do I convert to datetime?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `convert_dates` parameter in [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) with specify column name, here `a`, because not datelike column parsed by default:

> **convert_dates** : bool or list of str, default True
>
> List of columns to parse for dates. If True, then try to parse datelike columns. A column label is datelike if
>
> it ends with '_at',
>   it ends with '_time',
>   it begins with 'timestamp',
>   it is 'modified', or
>   it is 'date'.

```
df2 = pd.read_json(filename, convert_dates=['a'])
print(df2)
           a  b
0 2019-01-01  4
1 2019-01-02  5
2 2019-01-02  6
```